# Expressing two combined conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table with some data that i am interested in. The table is called trades. basically, i want to select all data in that table but this conditions must hold.

1. `trade_session_status="DONE"`
2. `(trade_prediction="up" AND trade_result="up" ) OR (trade_prediction="down" AND trade_result="down" )`

I have written the whole query like this

```
select * from trades where trade_session_status="DONE" AND
(trade_prediction="up" AND trade_result="up" ) OR
(trade_prediction="down" AND trade_result="down" )
```

I want to get all data where trade_session_status is "DONE" and someone predicted up and the result indeed came to be up or someone who predicted down and the result came to be down.

The query returns some data without any error. Is my query expression correct?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add additional brackets:

```
select * 
from trades
where trade_session_status="DONE" 
  AND ((trade_prediction="up" AND trade_result="up" ) 
        OR (trade_prediction="down" AND trade_result="down" ))
```

Alternatively:

```
select * 
from trades
where trade_session_status='DONE'
  AND (trade_prediction, trade_result) IN (('up', 'up'),('down', 'down'))
```